# Oracle SQL - how to group and aggregate results?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I am trying to query an audit table in Oracle to pull out a list of how popular a document is during a given timeframe (number of unique hits).

The SQL that I've developed so far is:

```
select distinct dt.name "Document name", ku.name "User name", count(*) "Number of hits" 
  from dauditnew da, 
       kuaf ku, 
       dtree dt 
 where ku.id=da.performerid 
   and (da.auditstr='Fetch') 
   and dt.dataid = ANY(DOCID1,DOCID2) 
   and da.dataid = ANY(DOCID1,DOCID2) 
   and da.auditdate between TO_DATE('01-JAN-12') and TO_DATE('31-OCT-12') 
 group by dt.name, ku.name
```

And it spits out data similar to:

```
Document name       User name           Hit count
document1.pdf   rimnet\user1    1
document1.pdf   rimnet\user2    1
document1.pdf   rimnet\user3    17
document1.pdf   rimnet\user4    1
document2.pdf   rimnet\user5    1
document1.pdf   rimnet\user6    1
document3.pdf   rimnet\user7    1
```

But what I really need is for it to group the results and count each unique user once:

```
Document name       User name           Hit count
document1.pdf       n/a                 5
document2.pdf       n/a                 1
document3.pdf       n/a                 1
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the results you want, it sounds like you just want a count of the users rather than a count of the hits (otherwise, it doesn't make sense to aggregate 17 hits + 1 hit + 1 hit + 1 hit + 1 hit and end up with 5 hits).  If that's the case

```
select dt.name "Document name", count(distinct ku.name) "Distinct users" 
  from dauditnew da, 
       kuaf ku, 
       dtree dt 
 where ku.id=da.performerid 
   and (da.auditstr='Fetch') 
   and dt.dataid = ANY(DOCID1,DOCID2) 
   and da.dataid = ANY(DOCID1,DOCID2) 
   and da.auditdate between TO_DATE('01-JAN-12') and TO_DATE('31-OCT-12') 
 group by dt.name
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Justin! This is definitely closer to what I'm looking for but it appears to be reporting the max value for both rows. The output says both DOC1 and DOC2 had 3 hits each but in reality its 1 and 3. Any idea why?

Comment: @user1810156 - Can you post a self-contained, runnable example that shows us the problem?  Post the DDL to create the tables (stripped down to the columns that play a role in the problem), post the DML to populate the tables with data, post the output the query is actually producing, and show us exactly what output you want.  Otherwise, we have to guess at what the data in your tables actually looks like.